# Eclipse error. valve The content of element type "jboss-web" must match ... jboss-web.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jboss, dtd

I use eclipse mars.2
I'm trying to import existing ecplipse project and i'm getting an error:

```
The content of element type "jboss-web" must match "(class-loading?,security-domain?,context-root?,virtual-host*,use-session-cookies?,replication-config?,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-role*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*,message-destination-ref*,message-destination*,webservice-description*,service-ref*,depends*,servlet*,authenticators*)".
```

jboss-web.xml   file

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
  "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN"
  "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_0.dtd">

<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/SPNEGO</security-domain>
<valve>
        <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

I don't understand why jboss-web_4_0.dtd doesn't contain vavlve. 
When i delete valve - the error disapears. But i need it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Alan,

you should use different xml declaration for jboss-web.xml as this element was introduced first in JBoss AS 7. Your file uses dtd file for JBoss AS 4.0.x. ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas
    http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_7_0.xsd">

...

</jboss-web>
```